# TryValidateObject and IValidatableObject not triggered

Tags: c#, validation, c#-4.0, data-annotations

I have a simple question (or not).

Why when I validate my object, the code below validate one part per time.

If DataAnnotations fails, Validate from IValidatableObject isn't called.
If DataAnnotations is OK, Validate from IValidatableObject is called.

My question is: Why? I see no reason for this. Am I missing something?

This is my class (e.g.):

```
class Foo : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var errors = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if (Date.Ticks > DateTime.Today.Ticks)
        {
            errors.Add(new ValidationResult("Some error.", new[] { "Date" }));
        }

        return errors;
    }
}
```

This is my validation:

```
var dto = new Foo();

validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
var context = new ValidationContext(dto, null, null);

Validator.TryValidateObject(dto, context, validationResults, true);

// Force
//var model = dto as IValidatableObject;

//if (model != null)
//{
//    validationResults.AddRange(model.Validate(context));
//}
```

Comment: By design? I didn't even realize that the IValidatableObject.Validate() method would trigger until I saw this post. I was trying to figure out why it didn't ever seem to fire. Did you ever find a way to make it fire every time?

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
private void ValidateIValidatableObject(IValidatableObject validatableObject, IList<ValidationResult> errors)
{
    var validations = validatableObject.Validate(null).ToList();

    validations.Where(vr => vr.MemberNames == null)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(vr => errors.Add(new ValidationResult(vr.ErrorMessage)));

    validations.Where(vr => vr.MemberNames != null)
        .SelectMany(vr => vr.MemberNames.Select(mn => new { MemeberName = mn, vr.ErrorMessage }))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(vr => errors.Add(new ValidationResult(vr.ErrorMessage, new string[] { vr.MemeberName })));
}
```

Usage:

```
IList<ValidationResult> errors = new List<ValidationResult>();

ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, errors, true);

if (model is IValidatableObject validatableObject)
{
    ValidateIValidatableObject(validatableObject, errors);
}
```

Credits: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5366